# Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception

Tags: spring, spring-ws

We are using Spring Web Services Maven dependency in our project.

Recently we upgraded the version of `spring-ws-core`: to 3.0.5.RELEASE

and spring-boot-starter-parent  to 2.1.0.RELEASE from 1.5.9

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After that, we are seeing below error on running the JAR. There is no compilation error though.

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
 [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'annotationActionEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/xml/DocumentBuilderFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.<clinit>(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:66)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.initDefaultStrategies(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:107)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:98)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractActionEndpointMapping.java:38)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.<init>(AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.java:34)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.<init>(AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.annotationActionEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d910591.CGLIB$annotationActionEndpointMapping$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d910591$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75c1c4c4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d910591.annotationActionEndpointMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Our web service class annotation looks like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "XYZService",
        portName = "XYZPort",
        targetNamespace = "http://www.scte.org/wsdl/130-3/2010/adm",
        endpointInterface = "org.scte.wsdl._130_3._2010.adm.ADM")
```

Comment: You also need to upgrade Spring, Spring WS 3.0.5 has a minimal required spring version. What is the Spring version you are using.

Comment: I also upgraded spring boot version its 2.1.0.RELEASE


<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the `spring-boot-starter-webservices` instead of manually defining the spring-ws version yourself. And then use the latest 2.1.4.RELEASE. That way you have matching versions.

Comment: @Deinum, Great I upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.1.4.RELEASE and now the problem is gone. Thank you so much.